# Java generics - wildcard with interface bound question

Tags: java, generics

Suppose that we have class `X` and generic class `Y`:

```
class X {}

class Y<T extends X> {}
```

Why is the following declaration legal?

```
Y<? extends Serializable> obj; //I understand this as any type extends X and Serializable
```

What I understand is that `?` means any type that satisfies `<T extends X>`, including `X`itself. So, subclasses of `X` that implement `Serializable` fits here. However,  `X` itself does not implement Serializable, so why does the previous declaration work?

Comment: As you correctly stated any subclass of X that implements Serializable would work here. Since X doesn't implement Serializable `obj = new Y<X>();` wouldn't work, so nothing unexpected here - or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Thomas, I agree that `new Y<X>()` will not compile. However, why the declaration itself works as long as X will not fit. For example, `Y<String> obj;` will not work because `String` doesn't extend `X`. Shouldn't `Y<? extends Serializable> obj;` be the same?

Comment: Well, as others have already stated `? extends Serializable` could still be anything that fits both the requirements and the compiler doesn't care what's assigned here as long as both restrictions are met. Those are checked when you assign a value to that variable and if the compiler realizes that `? extends Serializable` should be mapped to `X` it will complain about that. Btw, `? extends Number` wouldn't work because the compiler realizes that no class can extend `X` _and_ `Number` (it would work if `X` were an interface instead).

Comment: OK, I get it now, thanks a lot:)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I understand is that `?` means any type that satisfies `<T extends X>`, including `X` itself.

Yes, and you've added the additional restriction for the variable `obj` that the unknown type which `?` stands for, must implement `Serializable`.

> So, subclasses of `X` that implement `Serializable` fits here.

That's right.

> However, `X` itself does not implement `Serializable`, so why does the previous declaration work?

It doesn't matter that `X` does not implement `Serializable` - why should this matter?

The `extends Serializable` is just an additional restriction that you added to the type particularly for the variable `obj`.

Note that to the variable `obj` you can only assign a value that is an instance of a class that extends `X` and that also implements `Serializable`.

```
// Error! X does not implement Serializable, so this is not allowed
Y<? extends Serializable> obj = new Y<X>();

class Z extends X implements Serializable { ... }

// No problem, since Z extends X and also implements Serializable
Y<? extends Serializable> obj = new Y<Z>();
```

Comment: I thought type safety should work on both sides of the expression you've shown (`new Y<X>()`). So, I expected that the declaration should itself be wrong, like the assignment.

Comment: @mrboieng why should `new Y<X>()` not be allowed? The _class_ declaration of `Y` only has the restriction of the generic parameter being X or a subclass. The _variable_ declaration for `obj` has the additional restriction which affects the assignment but not the creation of the instance you want to assign.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid because in `? extends Serializable` ? is not determined yet &  `?` class must be implementing `Serializable` while it must be extending `X` per this definition. So, as soon as you provide assignment to this reference variable a type check would be done for that object (generics are to detect type error at compile time). The object must inherit Serializable as well as X else error will be shown.